# Looping through and appending to string from multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, append

I have four different arrays, each of differing lengths. I'm wanting to loop through each array in the following fashion. (NOTE: I'm only including a small number of values in each array here for ease of use, a solution must work regardless of the lengths of the arrays).

```
$array1 = ["A","B","C"];
$array2 = ["D","E","F","G","H"];
$array3 = ["I","J","K","L","M"];
$array4 = ["N","O","P","Q"];

$combinedArray = [];
```

I need each value in $combinedArray to contain a unique string, which consists of one element from each array. $combinedArray should have as many values as there are possible unique variations. So with the above example, there should be 300 (3*5*5*4) values in $combinedArray.

So each value in $combinedArray should look similar to the following:

```
$combinedArray[0] = "ADIN";
$combinedArray[1] = "BDIN";
$combinedArray[2] = "CDIN";
$combinedArray[3] = "AEIN";
...
$combinedArray[MAX] = "CHMQ";
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$array1 = ["A","B","C"];
$array2 = ["D","E","F","G","H"];
$array3 = ["I","J","K","L","M"];
$array4 = ["N","O","P","Q"];

$combinedArray = [];

foreach ($array1 as $a1){
    foreach ($array2 as $a2){
        foreach ($array3 as $a3){
            foreach ($array4 as $a4){
                $combinedArray[] = $a1 . $a2 . $a3 . $a4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing special. Just Nested loops. Hope this helps.